# iOS compare function

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare

I'm trying to understand what the standard way of writing a compare function is.

If I have an object `Person` with a property `age` and want to write my own compare function. I want to use it so that the Person objects are ordered from low age to high age.

i.e.

```
Person *young = [[Person alloc] initWithAge:10];
Person *old = [[Person alloc] initWithAge:80];
```

If I now run `[young compare:old]` should this return `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedAscending`?

I'm not sure which object is ascending or descending from which object (if that makes sense).

Comment: Wouldn't it be pretty simple to write it one way, run the comparison, and see if the order is what you expect? Easier than, say, posting the question and waiting for a response?

Comment: Yes but if I write it myself I can put it either way around.

Comment: How you place it is only meaningful when it's used, so if you use it, you'll have more than just an arbitrary decision (and enough to know if that decision was valid or opposite). If you were to place two Person objects in an NSArray, then sort the array using a comparison function that matches your guess, you would know immediately from the output if the elements were sorted according to your expectations (-> your decision was right), or contrary to them (-> reverse the sense of your comparison to fix it).

Comment: Alternatively you could look in the documentation for other classes that implement `compare:` (e.g. `NSNumber`) and see what they return.

Comment: @Sebastian I did that before coming here. Seems people don't like it when you ask questions here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of:

```
[obj1 compare:obj2]
```

Should be:

- `NSOrderedAscending` if when written as 'obj1, obj2' the objects are in ascending order;
- `NSOrderedDescending` if when written as 'obj1, obj2' the objects are in descending order;
- `NSOrderedSame` otherwise.

So you should see:

```
[@2 compare:@3] == NSOrderedAscending
[@"b" compare:@"a"] == NSOrderedDescending
```

etc. The way to remember it is to think about reading from left to right in whoever is doing the calling.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just lean on existing implementations

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(Person *)other;
{
  return [@(self.age) compare:@(other.age)];
}
```